# problems with flask render_template and make_response

Tags: python, html

I am new here and with python, I have de same problem, my code is simple

code index.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import make_response 

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def home():
#   return render_template ('home.html') 'before doing what was indicated in a similar problem
    return make_response(render_template('home.html'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

code home.html

```
<h1>Hi world </h1>
```

what am I doing wrong?

that executes the home.html and shows 'hi world'

Comment: You don't need the `make_response`.  Why are you adding it?

Comment: trying to solve the problem and because of a recommendation I saw on this site, it didn't have it. Thanks for help

Comment: What problem?  You haven't mentioned a problem.  In fact, you say it "shows 'hi world'", which is exactly what it should do.

Comment: while I was filling out the form and explaining the error, there was another form that told me to explain what I expected as a result, that's when I said to show 'hi world', that's what I expect, but it just shows an error.

Thanks for your interest in helping Robert

Comment: please Robert, take into account that it is my first time to enter this platform, it seems great to me.

Comment: But, go read your question.  You never mention an error.  Your question should say "I expected this to render "Hi world", but instead I got the following error:" and copy-and-paste the whole error message.  Right now, your question sounds like everything is working perfectly.